# How to extract numbers from a non-UTF-8 text file in Ruby and put them into another file?

Tags: python, ruby, regex, excel, terminal

I have some data recorded by the terminal and saved into a typescript file. I know I can change that to a .txt if desired. The problem seems to be that despite returning UTF-8 when asked for the file's encoding, the errors I get seem to hint at the encoding being something else. For example, I can't copy and paste the contents into Word or other text editors.

Anyways, I've had no luck doing the standard `.gsub!` or `.tr` methods to remove non-digit characters from this file.

The input looks like this:

```
_4ÑZŸs_4ÑZâ7o[?1034h
_4ÑZ8obash-3.2$ e4ÑZ”C
i[A e4ÑZõD
oscript -re4ÑZˇ?
i[Ae4ÑZ∑@
opython go.pyf4ÑZÌ
i
f4ÑZ£Ì
o
f4ÑZÊÚoattn 0
f4ÑZ,Ûoattn 0
attn 0
Hf4ÑZuÛoattn 0
attn 0
attn 0
attn 0
attn 0
attn 0
attn 0
```

where '0' can be any number between 0 and 128.

I only want the numbers after the word 'attn ' and not attn as well.

here's my current code:

```
File.open("input.txt").each do |line|
  number = line.gsub('[0-9]+', ' ')
  File.open("output.txt", "w+") { |f| f.write(number)  }
end
```

and depending on any of the small changes I've made, I either get an enumerator or just the last digit of the input file.

Never thought it would be this difficult to do something this basic.

Bonus points: What's the best way to have the program outputting these numbers to just insert them in either the 1st or 3rd columns of an excel sheet (indefinitely until I terminate the program in the terminal)?

The Python program generating the input file just takes values from a Serial object and outputs them to the terminal, which generates the text file in question. I'm ineptly just trying to move them manually from this text file to Excel (a task I am now foolishly trying to automate with a simple `Ruby` script).

A script in either Python or Ruby will suffice, so long as it takes a .txt file as input (since I'm working on data already generated).

I have a Mac, so I use Pages, if that makes a difference.

[Here](https://nofile.io/f/9njAtT2e2GJ/input.txt.zip) is the original file in question. EDIT: File removed for security reasons.

TL;DR

1. How do I print only the numbers in a typescript (seemingly non UTF-8) file on a new line (each number being 1-3 digits long)?
2. How do I automate this whole process and just have my Python program insert the values indefinitely (within an infinite `while True:` loop) into a `.numbers` (Excel for Mac) file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`(?<=^attn\s)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[01][0-9]|12[0-8])$`](https://regex101.com/r/t0YG3d/2) or `(?<=^attn\s)\d+`

Details:

- `(?<=)` Positive Lookbehind
- `\s` Matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `{n,m}` Matches between `n` and `m` times
- `|` Or

**Python code**:

```
text = open(r'C:\text.txt').read()
matches = re.findall(r'(?<=^attn\s)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[01][0-9]|12[0-8])$', text, re.M)
```

Output:

```
['11', '0', '99', '120', '0']
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/Qbyb8M)

Answer (score 0):

You should really split this question into two separate questions. Here is an answer to the first; some Ruby code that should do what you want:

```
numbers = File.readlines('input.txt').grep(/^attr \d+/).map do |line|
  line.split('attr ').last.chomp.to_i
end

File.write('output.txt', numbers.join("\n"))
```

Comment: this seems to work on other txt files but not the one i'm trying to use! 

I get this error:

    dataprocessor.rb:1:in `===': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 
    (ArgumentError)

but when I request the file's encoding, it comes up as UTF-8. What is going on?

Comment: UTF-8 is the default encoding, so the file will be opened in UTF-8 encoding mode even if the content is not valid UTF-8. It looks like that file is not a text file at all, but rather, a binary file. Because of this, it is not possible to reliably call `readlines`, because that opens the file in text mode, not binary mode. How was this data file created?

Comment: There is a Unix utility, `strings`, which scans a file, which can be a binary file, and outputs the strings it finds. You could use that, and even use your system's `grep`, to speed up your operation a bit and consume less memory: `strings input.txt` or with grep, `strings input.txt | grep "^attr \d"`. (I don't know the best regular expression on the command line without researching it more.) You'd need to use Shellwords.escape for quoted strings passed to the command line, doing `require shellwords` first.

Comment: `shellwords` in the above comment should have contained quotes, so it would be `require 'shellwords'`.

Comment: I used a bash command, "script -r", to record a terminal session. it automatically generated this file. Thank you so much for all this helpful information! You just saved me an incredible amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. The solution that ended up working for me was taking the binary file and running it through this script:

`strings input.txt | grep -o "\d.*" | uniq > output.txt`

which, as discussed, uses the Unix command `strings` to generate only the strings from the binary file, then runs a `grep` command to output only the unique instances of each number (unsorted, since its time-based data) to an output file. Then I just used Excel for further filtering.